# get the selected contact phone numbers from multi autocomplete textview

Tags: android

i am new to android, how to get phone numbers of selected contacts from MultiAutocompleteTextview when clicks on button ?
method to read contacts for multi-autocomplete textview

```
private void readContactData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String phoneNumber = "";
    String phoneName = "";
    phoneValueArr.clear();
    nameValueArr.clear();

    try{

    ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();

    cursor = content.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            PEOPLE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    if(null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            // Get Phone number
            phoneNumber =""+cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            phoneName = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phoneValueArr.add(phoneNumber.toString());
            nameValueArr.add(phoneName.toString());
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    //cursor.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

        Log.i("AutocompleteContacts","Exception : "+ e);

    }finally {
        //if (null != cursor)
            //cursor.close();
    }

    ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, cursor);
    mAuto.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

my ContactsListAdapter

```
public static class ContactListAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {
    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mContent = context.getContentResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
         final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

         View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_msg_custcontview,parent,false);
         return retView;

    }        

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        //((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(2));
        TextView pname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ccontName);
        TextView pnum = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ccontNo); 
        pname.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        pnum.setText(cursor.getString(1));

    }

    @Override
    public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        return cursor.getString(2);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
            return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
        }

        StringBuilder buffer = null;
        String[] args = null;
        if (constraint != null) {
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
        buffer.append("UPPER(");
        buffer.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
            args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
        }

        return mContent.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PEOPLE_PROJECTION,
                buffer == null ? null : buffer.toString(), args,
                null);
    }



    private ContentResolver mContent;           
}

private static final String[] PEOPLE_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
};
```

and how can i get my selected contact numbers into an object to store in database while pressing the button. And while loading contacts its giving an exception saying that

```
12-11 12:39:11.422: I/AutocompleteContacts(17735): Exception :   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 188
```

can any one help me ?

This is my multi auto complete OnItemClick Listener and its always giving index of selected name index -1

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// Get Array index value for selected name
int i = nameValueArr.indexOf(""+parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

// If name exist in name ArrayList
if (i >= 0) {

// Get Phone Number
toNumberValue = phoneValueArr.get(i);

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
        INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

   // Show Alert        
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position:"+position+" Name:"+parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" Number:"+toNumberValue,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", "Position:"+position+" Name:"+parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" Number:"+toNumberValue);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the multi-autocomplete OnItemclickListener issue by changing the code as below

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

TextView temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ccontNo);
TextView temp2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ccontName);
final String selectedNumber = temp.getText().toString();
final String selectedName = temp2.getText().toString();

if (selectedNumber != null) {


InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
        INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

   // Show Alert        
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Name:"+selectedName+" Number:"+selectedNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

Now i am getting the selected contact name and number. Then store those values in HashMap and while button click split the selected contacts by "," and iterate the loop for each name to get the contact number.

In this way i solved my problem hope it is helpful !! if so up Vote the answer!!!